# How to check progress of an already running lvresize command?

Tags: linux, lvm, ext4, oracle-linux, resize2fs

First, filesystem was backed up and unmounted succesfully.

Then, an lvresize was executed, and is already running:

```
lvresize --resizefs --size 1024G /dev/dbdrp/db
```

And shows the output:

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/mapper/dbdrp-db: 1718907/201326592 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 92969270/805304320 blocks
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/dbdrp-db to 268435456 (4k) blocks.
```

Filesystems output was the former:

```
[root@generic-linux-hostname ~]# df -hP
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/dbdrp-db  3.0T  310G  2.7T  11% /usr/local/oracle
```

And physical volumes tables where the following:

```
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/xvdc1 dbdrp    lvm2 a--   1.50t    0
  /dev/xvdd1 dbdrp    lvm2 a--   1.50t    0
```

After resizing finishes, one of this volumes will be pvremoved to recycle the virtual hard disk.

How can I see the progress of this lvresize? It's been running an hour, and not much information been thrown out.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3):

This may be an overshoot because I don't know the internals but, to have an idea, you can try the following:

Get the pid of the running process:

```
pgrep -afl resize2fs
2377 resize2fs -M /dev/vg0/lv-3
```

Here it was `resize2fs` but change to lvresize (if it is the command that actually does the resize).
Next, run `strace -e pread64,pwrite64 -p 2377` to monitor what are the syscalls that the command is doing so you will see from where it reads and where it writes to.

The output would be something like this:

```
pread64(3, "<!-- ..........................."..., 1236992, 2441878626304) = 1236992
pwrite64(3, "<!-- ..........................."..., 1236992, 181592702976) = 1236992
pread64(3, "<!-- ..........................."..., 479232, 2441880231936) = 479232
pwrite64(3, "<!-- ..........................."..., 479232, 181593939968) = 479232
```

and if you check the man page for `pread64`, you see that its signature is `ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset)` so, the last parameter of the call, is the offset or from which point of the block it is reading right now.
If you convert `2441880231936` bytes to TB, it would be roughly 2.2 TB and my volume as shown below has 3.44 TB, 2.2/3.34 = ~65%.
But, this is just a ballpark on where it is now because in that case, it will resize the partition to the minimum it can (because of resize2f -M) based on free space.
Also, I am not sure if ext4 (in my case) would write data into contiguous blocks, so it could be less work than the full disk.

```
lv-3 vg0  -wi-ao----  <3.34t
```

Answer (score 2):

The lvresize doesn't has progress bar option. But, if you do the resize in more step, you can check that:

1. Check the initial size of the fs:

```
# df -h /mnt
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects   19G  5.3G   13G  30% /mnt
```

2. umount:

```
# umount /mnt
```

3. check the fs:

```
# e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects: 13/1245184 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 1447987/4980736 blocks
```

4. resize the fs with progress (-p) option:

```
# resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects 6G
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects to 1572864 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 2 (max = 32768)
Relocating blocks             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 3 (max = 152)
Scanning inode table          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects is now 1572864 blocks long.
```

5. check the initial size of the LV:

```
# lvs vg00/vol_projects
  LV           VG   Attr     LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  vol_projects vg00 -wi-a--- 19.00g
```

6. resize the LV without resizefs option (we did in the earlier step):

```
# lvresize --size 6G /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects
  WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 6.00 GiB
  THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
Do you really want to reduce vol_projects? [y/n]: y
  Reducing logical volume vol_projects to 6.00 GiB
  Logical volume vol_projects successfully resized
```

7. check the size:

```
# lvs vg00/vol_projects
  LV           VG   Attr     LSize Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  vol_projects vg00 -wi-a--- 6.00g
```

8. mount and check the fs size:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects /mnt
# df -h /mnt
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-vol_projects  6.0G  5.3G  402M  94% /mnt
```

... but I think this way is more complicated :/